# How to get the values from two jsp pages forward and backword action in Struts2?

Tags: struts2

Hi I have Two JSP pages and Are references Same Struts Action class.When moving forward the Values from the first jsp page are available in the Second JSP.But when i click on the back button the values are empty.Can you please suggest me is there any way to available this values front and back forth actions.
Thanks in Advance.

First JSP:

```
<s:textarea name="incidentBean.description" id="descriptionId" 
    rows="2" cols="34" cssClass="textarea200" >
</s:textarea>
```

In my Second JSP:

```
<s:textarea name="descriptionId" id="descriptionId" readonly="true" 
    value="%{incidentBean.description}" 
    rows="2" cols="34" cssClass="textarea200" cssStyle="background-color: #C0C0C0">
</s:textarea>
```

Here is my Action  class

```
 public class BCMCaptureInitialIncidentAction extends DefaultActionSupport {
    private BCMInitialIncidentBean incidentBean;
    private String descriptionId;
    public BCMInitialIncidentBean getIncidentBean() {
        return incidentBean;
    }

    public void setIncidentBean(BCMInitialIncidentBean incidentBean) {
        this.incidentBean = incidentBean;
    }

    public String getDescriptionId() {
        return descriptionId;
    }

    public void setDescriptionId(String descriptionId) {
        this.descriptionId = descriptionId;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used for preparing the data to pre-populate the Capture Initial Incident Screen
     * @return String
     * @param
     * @exception BcmException
     * @exception BCMDatabaseException
     */
    public String prepareInitIncident(){
        System.out.println("prepareInitIncident Entered");
        if(incidentBean!=null)
            System.out.println("prepareInitIncident description:"+incidentBean.getDescription());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String validateCaptureIncident(){
        if(incidentBean!=null)
            System.out.println("validateCaptureIncident description:"+incidentBean.getDescription());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have incidentBean defined in your action class so the value is available in the second jsp while theirs is no scope for framework to set "descriptionId" when you coming back from the second jsp so value is unavailable to the first jsp

Answer (score 0):

You mean that when you click on some submit button and it goes back to the first jsp value are not there?

```
which values are you talking about?
```

first jsp values or second jsp values?. thing is on a request completion struts tend to clear value stack which is the primary storage for struts2 request processing cycle and for a new request it creates a new request object and place it in value stack.
Can only answer in more details if yo specify your use case in details.

**Edit**

As per the comment
If you click on submit button these values and request processing cycle starts struts2 place these values in the value-stack so they will be available for that particular request processing cycle.
On clicking the submit button from second jsp means a new request object will be created by framework and will be placed in the value stack.
so we have to maintain these values if we want them back in the first jsp.

```
**Edit2**
```

As per last comment if user click back button you have to move back value to first action so here you have following option.
since in second action you are showing the value entered by the user in the text area so when user want to go back this value will be set in to the `descriptionId` property. so now you can do following thing

```
<s:textarea name="incidentBean.description" id="descriptionId" 
    rows="2" cols="34" cssClass="textarea200" value="%{descriptionId}" >
</s:textarea>
```

just take care about `value="%{descriptionId}"` when you will show the jsp first time.

Comment: Yes Umesh,when I click on some submit button and it goes back to the first jsp value are not there.I have two values lets say a,b in First JSP,am getting these two values in Second JSP but when am clicking back button in Second JSP these a,b values are not available in First JSP.

Comment: @Rakesh: are you moving these values back to the action and setting them in value stack they will only be available if you set them in value stack

Comment: :Here is the Code:In my first JSP: <s:textarea name="incidentBean.description" id="descriptionId"  rows="2" cols="34" cssClass="textarea200" ></s:textarea>                           In my Second JSP:<s:textarea name="descriptionId" id="descriptionId"  readonly="true" value="%{incidentBean.description}" rows="2" cols="34" cssClass="textarea200" cssStyle="background-color: #C0C0C0"></s:textarea>

Comment: can you show the action class? just add that to you question as a code

Comment: :Can you give any examples or code to maintain these values if we want them back in the first jsp.I have no idea how to set in the stack.

Comment: ypu must be going back by action so do the following step.in you action class declare two properties with the name "incidentBean.description" and "descriptionId" and generate there getter and setter.framework will set them to these respected fields and they will be available in value Stack.Suggest you to read struts2 documentation about request processing value stack and interceptors

Comment: @Rakesh what exactly you want to show in ur first jsp and where?

Comment: :If let's take an examples the user enter some values in the First Jsp,i will show the confirmation in the second jsp,If user want to modify he will click on the back button,but the textbox am loosing the value which is entered by the user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5191/discussion-between-rakesh-and-umesh-awasthi)